# can't get the right cron job timing

Tags: linux, cron, debian, cron-task

i'm trying to do some stuff automatically every 8 Weeks, so i had open a new user crontab like this one:

```
crontab -e
0 9 * */2 1-5 do_this_stuff
# do it every 2 month on monday till friday at 9:00 am
```

This should do the job every 2 month on monday till friday on 9:00 am, but i does not. It is doing the job evey week once. Don't get it. What i'm doing wrong?

Running System is a latest debian.

regarding http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Cron it should run fine

Comment: Which `cron` have you installed ? I believe this syntax is Vixie cron specific...

Comment: how i do find it out?

Comment: What does your log files say (e.g. `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, ...)? Did your `do_this_stuff` script do some `syslog(3)`-ing perhaps thru `logger(1)` command? Is it executable? In the standard `PATH`? Consider putting the full file path in the `crontab` entry....

Comment: The Anwer is, cron can't do a job randomly on a random day in a month. I had to change my crontab to: 0 9 1 */2 * do_sm_stuff -- this runns every two Month always on the first Day in a Month the cron

Comment: Good to read it is solved. Maybe you can update your question or post an answer, so next people entering can know you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The Anwer is, cron can't do a job randomly on a random day in a month. I had to change my crontab to: 0 9 1 */2 * do_sm_stuff -- this runs every two Month always on the first Day in a Month

thank you [Igor](https://plus.google.com/112457602357038466754/posts/fkqCohzSkCw)